# css transition on one image causes nearby images jitter

Tags: css, css-transitions

Why a mouse over transition in one image causing a jitter in nearby images?

The images are large and fits in the div with `width:100%`.

[image]

Observed the issue in chrome.

```
.post:hover figure img {
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
.post img {
  transition: all cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1) .3s;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Share the URL or full code. Its very hard to find the issue without them.

Answer (score 0):

```css
     /* Main Div css start here */
    .slide_Wrapper {
        display: flex;
    }
    /* This is for child div */
    .slide {
        width: 290px;
        height: 160px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #000;
        margin:10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    /* This is for child div border */
    .slide::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 90%;
        height: 82%;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        z-index: 2;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    /* Background images */
    .slide img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        transition: all cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1) .3s;
        transform: scale(1);
        position: absolute;
    }
    /* Background images on hover */
    .slide:hover img {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    /* Text */
     .slide h2{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        color: #fff;
     }
```

```html
<!-- Here I create a main div and two child div -->
<div class="slide_Wrapper">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
      <h2>XYZ</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
      <h2>ABC</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you have done that gets rid of the jitter?

Comment: I create a `div` with class name `slide`. In side `slide` we have content img and h2 for text.

and your main issue with box border when you hover on one the other one is blinking so I put border in `:after`  tag.